# Trouble removing an event listener set in an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a slider (ex: http://jqueryui.com/slider/) in pure javascript (no libraries) and am having trouble getting the `addEventListener` / `removeEventListener` to operate as I'm expecting them. Basically, I keep running into an issue where I lose the scope of the `mousemove` listener object when I drill down into the `mouseup` listener, and am unable to remove the `mousemove` event listener and stop the dragging process.

I've also tried to create an object with an EventListener interface (for example, as described here: http://ajaxian.com/archives/an-alternative-way-to-addeventlistener) but run into the same problem. I'd really like to pursue that route if possible.

How about some code. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-bar"></div>
  <div id="slider-1" class="slider-ball"></div>
</div>
```

Here's an example of some javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Slider(elem) {
  this.elem = elem;

  this.listen = function() {
    this.elem.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mouseDown, false);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp, false);
  }

  this.mouseDown = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseDrag, false);
  }

  this.mouseUp = function() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseDrag, false);
  }

  this.mouseDrag = function(e) {
    // code to move the slider-ball on its X axis.
  }
}

newSlider = new Slider(document.getElementById('slider-1'));
newSlider.listen();
</script>
```

I've tried many different approaches – prototype methods, a singleton function, internal methods (e.g. above), but in all of these cases when I run something along the lines of `this.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mouseDown, false);` I lose the scope of `this` object in `mouseDown`. I've used `bind()` to pass the value along – `this.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mouseDown.bind(null, this), false);` to pass the DOM object along while keeping the event parameter in `mouseDrag`. Cool! Except in those cases I've been consistently unable to ever **remove** the event listener. The only exception to this is if I set the `mousemove` event listener via `this.elem.addEventListener...`, but in this case my `mousemove` function only runs when the cursor is moving while over the object and not anywhere in the document, which is the desired behavior.

I could do this in a bunch of standalone functions using global vars to reference the attached events, but I'm trying to learn to do this within an object.

Comment: A jsfiddle of this may be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use bind.
You have 2 choice:

- when you attach the event
- when you attache function function to this.

Like this:

```
function Slider(elem) {
  this.elem = elem;

  this.listen = function() {
    this.elem.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mouseDown.bind(this), false);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp.bind(this), false);
  }

  this.mouseDown = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseDrag, false);
  }

  this.mouseUp = function() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseDrag, false);
  }

  this.mouseDrag = function(e) {
    // code to move the slider-ball on its X axis.
  }.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: That's perfect! I didn't realize I could attach `bind` to the function definition like that. I need to read up on this. Thank you.

Comment: If you need compatibility to old browser use mozilla polify : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fbind#Compatibility

Comment: Do you know how far back in IE I can go with addEventListener / bind? I think it's IE9+.